# How to access JSON response from external class - Javascript

Tags: json, response

I know this should be simple, but I'm new to a project and can't figure out how to get this value returned.  I've tried "this", "this.snippet", message.whatever, etc.  Just for example purposes, how would I get the properties.network_id from the response?

caller:

```
v1.value.getSnippet(topology).then(function() {
        console.log("snippet ->: " + JSON.stringify());
        //delete topology.extraData;
    });
```

calling:

```
 getSnippet: function(topology) {
        if (!this.snippet) {
            if (!this.promise) {
                var self = this;
                this.promise =  xhr(uReleaseConfig.urls.rest + "/cloud/network/" + this.id, {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json"
                    },
                    handleAs: "text"
                }).then(function (response) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(response || null);
                    self.snippet = data.message;
                }, function(error){
                    self.error = error;
                 });
            }
            return this.promise;
        }
        return this.snippet;
    }
```

response:

```
{"message":"{\"__name_placeholder__\":{\"type\": \"OS::Neutron::Net\", \"properties\": {\"network_id
\": \"b2ac2526-ae8f-4d82-b1da-8d77b79f3476\", \"external\":\"false\", \"subnets\": [{\"id\":\"a1e3441e-4dcc-4c4a-ac12-2b60fe440c51
\",\"name\":\"product-dev-subnet-ben\",\"cidr\":\"192.168.20.0\\\/24\"},{\"id\":\"e2e05590-5539-45bb-995e-8f565e6c16ff
\",\"name\":\"product-dev-subnet\",\"cidr\":\"192.168.10.0\\\/24\"}] }}}\n"}
```

Comment: You do realize your response is just a single key of `"message"` with the value of a really long string, right? You'd need to parse that value to get `properties.network_id`

Comment: I'm not too worried at this point, but still get "undefined" when logging "message" and "this.message"

Answer (score 0):

I needed a var in the return val:

```
.then(function(returnVal)

console.log("snippet ->: " + JSON.stringify(returnVal));
```